# Swift: Conforming to protocols using default values

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to conform to a Swift protocol using default values?

The following example results in a `Type 'FunExample' does not conform to protocol 'Example'`:

```
protocol Example {
    func doSomething(with: String)
}

class FunExample: Example {
    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool = true) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

...even though I actually implicitly conform since this is identical to:

```
protocol Example {
    func doSomething(with: String)
}

class FunExample: Example {
    func doSomething(with: String) {
        self.doSomething(with: with, butMakeItFun: true)
    }
    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to provide conformance using default values? Or am I missing something conceptually when I say that the first example *should* also pass conformance?

To clarify: I understand *why* the error is produced. My question is more conceptual (whether Swift *should* work this way) and whether there is an elegant way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research & thinking, it turns out that it is conceptually correct for Swift *not* to support this.

The idea of protocol conformance is to *ensure* that your class fits certain requirements and can provide that functionality without issue. This cannot be achieved if there would be implicit conformance.

Why? Consider the original example, slightly modified:

```
protocol Example {
    func doSomething(with: String)
}

class FunExample: Example {
    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool = true) {
        // implementation
    }
    func doSomething(with: String, andDoSomeOtherStuffWith parameter: String = "") {
        // another implementation
    }
}
```

*If* Swift were to assume that `func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool = true)` conforms to `func doSomething(with: String)` because of the default values, then this would introduce ambiguity (since the other doSomething function also conforms).

To put it another way, here `FunExample` does not actually implement the feature `doSomething(with: "Asdf")` implicitly because simply calling this function on the class would result in an `Ambiguous use of 'doSomething'` error.

As such, it is conceptually not possible to rely on default values to implicitly assume protocol conformance.

Comment: I'll add the caveat that the Swift compiler _could_ in theory check if your implementation produces ambiguity and - if it does - warn you to provide an implementation without a default value to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with `extension` for the more cleaner way! Make an `extension` with the same `protocol` methods and pass the default values which you want. Let's say:

```
protocol Example { //Main Protocol
    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool)
}

extension Example { //Make to pass the default values if you want
    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool = false) {
        return doSomething(with: with, butMakeItFun: butMakeItFun)
    }
}

class FunExample: Example { //Protocol Acceptance
    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool) {
        debugPrint("\(with)")
        debugPrint(butMakeItFun)
    }
}
```

You can call it via following ways:

1. `FunExample().doSomething(with: "Hello Default Values...")`
2. `FunExample().doSomething(with: "..........", butMakeItFun: true)`

> Update

So based on your comment, here is what I have came up! You can take a variable under the `protocol` which surely says `true` or `false` as a default implementation and later-on you can change it in your `class`.

```
protocol Example {
    var isFun: Bool {set get}
    func doSomething(with: String)
}

class FunExample: Example {

    //var isFun: Bool = false - In case you want to change value

    func doSomething(with: String) {
        doSomething(with: with, butMakeItFun: isFun)
    }

    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool) {
        debugPrint(with)
        debugPrint(butMakeItFun)
    }
}

extension Example {
    var isFun: Bool {
        get { return true /* Your Default Value */ } set {}
    }
}
```

Comment: The original protocol is defined without the butMakeItFun parameter (unlike in your example). And I wouldn't want to include anything "fun" in the Example protocol (as this would then apply to potentially unfun classes that implement Example).

Comment: Unfortunately this still introduces "fun" dependencies into the original Example protocol. Consider that Example-implementing classes could provide unlimited additional features in the future (fun, colorful, shiny, etc.). In your example I would need to know in advance _all_ possible extensions and add isColorful, isShiny, etc. properties for each.

Or to put it specifically: my goal would be to achieve this even though I cannot (or at least should not) change the original protocol implementation.

Comment: I believe this is not possible in the way I intended. Take a look at my explanation (in the accepted answer).

Comment: @Aron Well thanks, but I don't think so because in both the methods you are passing the value `true`. Besides, if you want to pass the `false` value you can just take down the variable in the class, no need to conform the protocol because at last you are just confirming `func doSomething(with: String)` which can be easily done in regular way!

Comment: I clarified my answer example to show how the ambiguity is relevant even if the parameters are completely different (not both boolean and true).

Comment: @Aron Cool! Well, you can think of my approach or you can keep in mind for future use, Good luck :D

Answer (score 1):

As your example code is written, your FunExample does not conform because it does not have a function `func doSomething(with: String)`.

`func doSomething(with: String)` and `func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool)` are not the same. So it doesn't conform.

When you add the following code it will conform

```
func doSomething(with: String) {
    self.doSomething(with: with, butMakeItFun: true)
}
```

I would provide a default implementation of doSomething(with: String) and then 'decorate' it where needed.

```
protocol Example {
    func doSomething(with: String)
}

extension Example {
    func doSomething(with text: String) {
        print(text)
    }
}

class FunExample: Example {
    func doSomething(with: String, butMakeItFun: Bool) {

        if butMakeItFun() {
          playTheSound()
          releaseBalloons()
        }

        return doSomething(with: String)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution in _certain_ cases, but it makes the assumption that I can provide a default implementation for `doSomething(with text: String)`. This may or may not be the case.