# TableView not conforming to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I've set up a basic CellAssociation protocol.

However, anything I add to the protocol gets an:

```
"Type 'FooTableView' does not conform to protocol 'Cell Association'"
```

There are some tips Xcode seems to be giving me:

```
"Multiple maching functions named 'register(cellClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)' with type '(AnyClass?, String) -> ()' (aka '(Optional<AnyObject.Type>, String) -> ()')"
```

and..

```
"Rename to 'register(cellClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)' to satisfy this requirement"
```

However, it looks like my register function is named that.

Here's the CellAssociation (TableView.swift)

```
import UIKit

protocol CellAssociation {
    associatedtype Cell: UITableViewCell

    func register()
    func register(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)

    func dequeueReusableCell(for: IndexPath) -> Cell
    func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String, for: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
}

extension CellAssociation {

    func register() {
        register(cellClass: Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self))
    }

    func dequeueReusableCell(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell {
        return dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self), for: indexPath) as! Cell
    }
}
```

Here's a TableView attempting to conform to the protocol:

```
import UIKit

class LineupDraftSortMenuTableView: UITableView, CellAssociation {

    typealias Cell = LineupDraftSortMenuCell

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .plain)
        setup()
    }

    required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }

    func setup() {
        rowHeight = 40
        separatorStyle = .none
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        register()
    }
}
```

This class will throw an error:

```
"Type 'LineupDraftSortMenuTableView' does not conform to protocol 'CellAssociation'"
```

And LineupDraftSortMenuCell

```
import UIKit

class LineupDraftSortMenuCell: UITableViewCell {

    let optionLabel = DraftboardLabel()
    let iconCheck = UIImageView()

    let borderView = UIView()

    var selectedOption: Bool = false { didSet { toggleIconCheck() } }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }

    func setup() {
        addSubviews()
        setupSubviews()
        addConstraints()
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        contentView.addSubview(optionLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(iconCheck)
        contentView.addSubview(borderView)
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        selectionStyle = .none

        optionLabel.font = UIFont.openSans(weight: .Semibold, size: 9)
        optionLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        optionLabel.letterSpacing = 0.5

        iconCheck.image = UIImage(named: "icon-check")
        iconCheck.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iconCheck.isHidden = !selectedOption

        borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(0x5c656f)
    }

    func addConstraints() {
        let viewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
            optionLabel.leftRancor.constraintEqualToRancor(rancor: contentView.leftRancor, constant: 20),
            optionLabel.centerYRancor.constraintEqualToRancor(rancor: contentView.centerYRancor),
            iconCheck.widthRancor.constraintEqualToConstant(constant: 12),
            iconCheck.heightRancor.constraintEqualToConstant(constant: 10),
            iconCheck.centerYRancor.constraintEqualToRancor(rancor: contentView.centerYRancor),
            iconCheck.rightRancor.constraintEqualToRancor(rancor: contentView.rightRancor, constant: -20),
            borderView.leftRancor.constraintEqualToRancor(rancor: contentView.leftRancor, constant: 10),
            borderView.rightRancor.constraintEqualToRancor(rancor: contentView.rightRancor, constant: -10),
            borderView.bottomRancor.constraintEqualToRancor(rancor: contentView.bottomRancor),
            borderView.heightRancor.constraintEqualToConstant(constant: 1),
        ]

        optionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iconCheck.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        borderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(viewConstraints)
    }

    func toggleIconCheck() {
        iconCheck.isHidden = !selectedOption
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `LineupDraftSortMenuCell`?

Comment: I added the the class definition to the post, hope it helps!

Comment: Check the answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your protocol has this requirement:

```
protocol CellAssociation {
    func register(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)
}
```

But your table view subclass, LineupDraftSortMenuTableView, never implements that method. So it does not conform to the protocol.

Perhaps you are assuming that that function declaration is matched by something UITableView already implements, so that a UITableView subclass can conform to your protocol without explicitly implementing it. But that's not the case. The method that UITableView already has is:

```
func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

The underscore makes a big difference!

Thus, your code will compile if you rewrite the protocol and its extension to match what UITableView already implements, like this:

```
protocol CellAssociation {
    associatedtype Cell: UITableViewCell
    func register()
    func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)
    func dequeueReusableCell(for: IndexPath) -> Cell
    func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String, for: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
}

extension CellAssociation {
    func register() {
        register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self))
    }
    func dequeueReusableCell(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell {
        return dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self), for: indexPath) as! Cell
    }
}
```

Once you've said that, it becomes legal to say:

```
class LineupDraftSortMenuTableView: UITableView, CellAssociation {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: A minor update to `dequeueReusableCell` by adding `indexPath` in signature as this `func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 2):

Actually recently, I have almost came across the question of your which you can refer ([Swift: Conforming to protocols using default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987306/swift-conforming-to-protocols-using-default-values/52987550?noredirect=1#comment92997396_52987550)).

So taking that reference, here is the modified version for your code.

```
protocol CellAssociation {
    associatedtype Cell: UITableViewCell

    func register(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)
    func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
}

extension CellAssociation {

    func register(cellClass: AnyClass? = Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String = String(describing: Cell.self)) {
        return register(cellClass: cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: forCellReuseIdentifier)
    }

    func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String = String(describing: Cell.self), forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: withIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

What I have done is, I have passed default values as you have created a different method for it which is confirmed in the `extension`. Now, it will confirm the `protocol`. Let me know, if you have any more questions or issues.

Comment: How would I call dequeueResusableCell(withIdentifier:for indexPath:) Using withIdentifier's default value but still inputting indexPath's value?

Comment: Not yet, any help would be appreciated!